# How to display data on dynamodb in django admin page?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, admin

My django project have a `postgres` database to contain user data. And also I have items on `dynamodb`.

With the help of django admin, showing all information about users on admin page is done easily. 
But I wonder if there are any ways to display and filter data on dynamodb like the ones on postgres?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a `Scan` operation on your DynamoDB table and display records on your admin page. `Scan` supports both filters and pagination, which might be helpful for your use case.

See documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html).